# Error in code preview with tabs

Tags: bug, markdown-preview, tabs

When I type this: (characters separated by a single tab)

```
a   b
~   c
```

It actually displays as this in the preview window:

```
a   b
~  c
```

But it seems to display correctly when posted.

It seems to relate to the `~` character.

This reproduces on at least Chrome and IE.

Since some people seem to want a question - What's causing this and can it be fixed?

Comment: Yep. The preview converts tab character to three spaces when inside code block or <pre> tag, but in case of `~` in the beginning, tab is converted only to two spaces in preview, causing this phenomenon. Weird, as I don't think `~` has any special meaning for markdown.

Comment: Tabs, just one of the Devil's contributions to computing.

Comment: @GrantThomas Only in code... And if you can't set the tab stop positions.

Comment: @Grant I think `F1` caused much more heads to be banged against the nearest solid thing.

Comment: I cannot repro this when editing this post on Chrome 28.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm also on Chrome 28. What OS? I'm on Windows. I can't really think of any other probable determining factors.

Comment: Yup, Windows 7 here. I don't know, it works fine for me both when editing inline and when copying-and-pasting in. I've made sure to turn off all extensions, too.